# Error occurred during initialization of VM java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ide

I am trying to install cosulo ide for unity game development. I have installed jdk 17 and set JAVA_HOME. when run ./consulo.sh it gives this message:

```
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: package com.apple.eawt not in java.desktop
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: package com.apple.laf not in java.desktop
WARNING: package com.apple.eawt.event not in java.desktop
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
WARNING: Unknown module: consulo.container.impl specified to --add-opens
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.InternalError: Could not create SecurityManager
at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@17.0.8/System.java:2226)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     consulo.container.impl.securityManager.impl.ConsuloSecurityManager
at jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.8/BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.8/ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.base@17.0.8/ClassLoader.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@17.0.8/Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@17.0.8/Class.java:467)
at java.lang.System.initPhase3(java.base@17.0.8/System.java:2210)`
```

i am using this version consulo.dist.linux64_3355.tar.gz
I dont understand what should i do or how to fix it? I am very new in unity and face trouble using vs code and rider which is not free.Thanks for your time.

I have tried using chat gpt and forums but no luck.